# How to make LinearLayout fill available space when some elements are not set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

In my activity I have LinearLayout with 4 elements:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton1"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:background="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I have all 4 elements set the layout is rendered as following:
[image: Result when all 4 elements are set]

Which is as I want it. The problem occurs when one or more of the elements are not present and I get the following result:

[image: Result when only 3 elements are set]

How can I make my elements spread over all available space? So when only 2 elements have their background set the result should look something like:
[image: Expected result when 2 elements are set]

Instead of how it looks now:
[image]

Comment: for parent LinearLayout set android:gravity="center".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use weight so when no view will be there it will adjust automatically

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@null" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@null" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton3"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:background="@null" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton4"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@null" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `android:gravity="center"` will align all the child view in `center`,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"    
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

   ... your code

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use android:layout_width="0dp" instead of  android:layout_width="wrap_content" for all ImageButton. as you are setting  android:layout_weight for all that view.

Comment: android:layout_width="0dp" and dynamic changing of weights in code 0 <--> 1 did the trick. Thank you :)